# Find if the installed PHP is threadsafe or nonthreadsafe?

Tags: php, iis, thread-safety

How do I find out whether the installed version of PHP is threadsafe or not thread safe?

Please note that I'm not asking the difference between a threadsafe/non thread safe installation. I would like to find out what is installed currently.

Comment: see answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php

Comment: @Haim Thats not my question Haim. I saw that thread. I have PHP already installed on this server. Its working with IIS. But,I need to findout which setup was used to install this...Threadsafe setup/ the non theadsafe setup?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Open a phpinfo() and search for the line *Thread safety*. For a thread-safe build you should find *enable*.

As specified in the comments by [Muhammad Gelbana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897041/muhammad-gelbana) you can also use:

- On Windows : `php -i|findstr "Thread"`
- On *nix: `php -i|grep Thread`

Comment: On Windows: `php -i|find "Thread"`
On *nix: `php -i|grep Thread`

Comment: Note to self: `php -i | find "Architecture"` to check if it is x86 or x64

Comment: @checksum it's `php -i | grep Architecture`

Answer (score 27):

If you prefer to use the command line:

- *nix:

  ```
  php -i | grep -i "Thread"
  ```
- Windows:

  ```
  php -i | findstr -i "thread"
  ```

This should give you something like this:

```
Thread Safety => enabled
```

or

```
Thread Safety => disabled
```

Comment: Not a very good idea, since the PHP version used by the server can be different from the one picked up by the OS (the default).

Answer (score 9):

I just find it easier to look at the file named php[version].dll in the root folder of php. Its either php[version].dll or php[version]ts.dll (ts standing for Thread Safe). So, if you have php7.0.10 installed, go to the directory that has this name and you'll find a file named php7ts.dll. This is a very sad way of finding out, but it works!

Answer (score 8):

Then there's the undocumented `ZEND_THREAD_SAFE` constant, which seems to exist since PHP 4.3.

```
<?php

if (ZEND_THREAD_SAFE) {
    echo 'Thread safe';
} else {
    echo 'Not thread safe';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tALKX

Answer (score 4):

Create a new PHP file and insert this code in it:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then run this page and you will find all of the PHP information. Search for the term that you want, and it will show you it's enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your install is Apache Module or CGI Binary. See Stack Overflow question *[What is thread safe or non-thread safe in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914)*.

Comment: How do I check that? Ofcourse its being used by IIS..But how do I findout what module it is? That was my question...I don't mean to ask the difference between threadsafe/non thread safe. I need to know whether the installed version is thread safe/not

Comment: Ok i just investigated a bit, and yes there are [2 builds](http://windows.php.net/download/) available; safe and non-safe. According to this [install guide for IIS7](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) non-thread-safe installs are recommended. Could you open up a phpinfo() and se if the word 'thread' apears anywhere?

Comment: yeah,phpinfo had the info in it...Just found it...Thanks @Philiplip

Answer (score 2):

Another way to check it is using `php -v` or `php --version`. Example bellow from mine (NTS):

```
    $ php --version
    
    PHP 7.3.25-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 26 2020 10:32:51) ( NTS )       
    Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v3.3.25, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.25-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```