# Class 'Memcached' not found in laravel

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, memcached

I am trying to run simple code of cache using memcache in my laravel project.

I have added `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached` in my .env file.

I have created folder of memcache in C drive and added a file memcache.exe in that, and run in cmd by opening it as administrator.

my code in route is:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
//    return view('welcome');
    Cache::put('k1','created memcached memory!!',1);
    Cache::add('k2','used "add" in memcached!!',2);
    Cache::forever('k3','using forever to create cache',3);
    $k1 = Cache::get('k1','default');
    $k2 = Cache::pull('k2','default');
    $k3 = Cache::pull('k3','default');
    Cache::forget('k1');
    $check = 0;
    if(Cache::has('k1')){
        return $check = 1;
    }
});
```

when I run this route, i get error as

> Class 'Memcached' not found

Is there any solution?

**EDIT:**

When i remove `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached` and use `CACHE_DRIVER=file` above code runs fine. What is correct way `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached` or `CACHE_DRIVER=file`? I had referred that from [video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goD7wM_-0zw)

Comment: You need to install the PHP extension for memcached, otherwise memcached-related classes won't be available

Comment: Can you provide me correct link for php extensions?

Comment: Windows & Ubuntu installation notes https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451979/1689770

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the `memcached` extension to your server.

If you are using linux then

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
```

Here is the launchpad [link](https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/+download) and here's [pecl's link](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached)

**Update :**

If you are using xampp in windows you should just do this

In your `php.ini` file just remove the semi colon before this

```
;extension=php_memcache.dll
```

to

```
 extension=php_memcache.dll
```

and then restart your server

**Note :**

Don't forget to restart or stop and start your server after you install this.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Thanks for reminding, i will add accordingly

Comment: It can be difficult to use Memcache or Memcached in Windows; if you are only working on your localhost or your project won't have a real use, you can implement redis or files (if you use files, your project couldn't be optimized). But if your project is a real project that will have requests from thirds, you can use a Ubuntu server (considering that you only work with Laravel) or implement Redis in your Windows Server.

Comment: @GilbertoSánchez Can Memcached (with a 'd') ever work on Windows? I'm having tons of trouble at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777857/how-to-install-and-use-memcached-in-windows-for-php#comment73465638_23320151

Comment: What about when getting the error? ```E: Unable to locate package php5-memcached``` or ```E: Unable to locate package php-memcached```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install memcached
sudo yum install php-memcached
```

Replace `yum` with `apt-get` or `dnf` as necessary. No other changes needed, after running these it worked.

Then run `memcached --version` to check if it's been installed.

Comment: You have to run `sudo systemctl enable memcached` and `sudo systemctl start memcached` after installing.