# Memcache for PHP7 on Windows?

Tags: windows, memcached, php-7

Does any one know about a Memcache version that supports PHP7 on Windows?

Memcache is working great for PHP 5.6 (on Windows), but I cannot find the version for PHP7.

Comment: Great question, by the way.

Comment: Various ways to get memcache[d] https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451979/1689770

Answer (score 37):

Please find php_memcache.dll for **php7.0.x, php7.1.x, php7.2.x**
https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll

- **vc14** & **vc15**
- **x86** & **x64**
- **ts** & **nts**

Comment: Does a version of php_memcache.dll exist for PHP Version 7.0.0, or should the 7.0.6 dll version work for it?

Comment: the 7.0.6 version should work for 7.0.0. If not, contact me and i'll provide the 7.0.0 compiled version

Comment: i've just add php_memcache.dll build with php 7.1.0 sources. see https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcahe-dll#php-71x_memcachedll

Comment: You're welcome! VC15 builds added and url change (corrected...) https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll

Comment: Please can we also get sources and dependencies for php_memcache on 7.0.X and PHP 7.1.X to compile it on Windows independently?

Comment: When I attempt to build independently, I get this error: 
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) : error LNK2005: __snprintf already defined in zlib_a.lib(gzlib.obj)
Any ideas what I am missing?  @nono303

Comment: @VladacusB : Please refer to https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild for windows build. Use php-src from https://github.com/php/php-src branch to have  7.0.X and PHP 7.1.X independently

Comment: @BradThiessen: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728649/error-lnk2005-xxx-already-defined-in-msvcrt-libmsvcr100-dllc-something-libc ? If not can you detail your MSVC & php-dep package versions?

Comment: Thanks @nono303.  I ended up figuring it out!  My issue was that I was using VC13.

Comment: Updated 7.2.x version patched with pull #26 https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache/pull/26/ to fix issue #23 https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache/issues/23#issuecomment-327702906 :Failed to read session data with 7.1/7.2

Comment: memcache worked for me with windows10 iis. use the OP's link, get the memcache dll you need (mine was the 7.2.x nts x86 one). Also a side note, for nts x86 mssql drivers, check into this link.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 8):

1. At first, check phpinfo(), example:

   - Compiler: MSVC14 <strike>(Visual C++ 2015)</strike>
   - Architecture: **x64**
   - PHP Extension Build: API20160303,**NTS**,**VC14**
2. Based on information in phpinfo(); choose right dll:

   - Source: https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll
   - Folder (based on example): **vc14** / **x64** / **nts**
3. Copy to php_memcache.dll to \PHP\v7.1\ext
4. Enable php_memcache in php.ini, add line:

   - extension=php_memcache.dll
5. Check presentation of 'memcache' section in phpinfo();
6. Check errors.log

Answer (score 4):

Here is the dll you can use with your PHP7 Windows installation (64 bit)

https://github.com/Alvine-IO/php7-windows/blob/master/x64/ts/dll/php_memcache.dll

Comment: TS + NTS Version found here: https://github.com/Alvine-IO/php7-windows/tree/master/7.0.3/x64

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if anyone needs dll files - https://github.com/jur4x/PHP7-memcahe-dll.
Compiled for PHP 7.0.6, both thread safe and non thread safe versions.

Comment: How did you compile memcached.lib? When I try to compile, I am getting the error `ERROR: memcached: library 'memcached' not found`

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.23/ext/php_memcache.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 2):

The new `memcached` extension doesn't work on Windows because `libmemcached` doesn't work on Windows. However, someone seems to have gotten the old `memcache` extension to install on Windows. I can't find a nice pre-compiled binary, but, after a lot of digging, I found a [PHP Bug Report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70751) about this issue. Someone there seems to have found a solution:

> **[2016-01-20 23:11 UTC] php at alternize dot com**
>
> the branch "NON_BLOCKING_IO_php7" of the git repository https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache.git builds fine against php 7.0.2 in win32 x86 thread-safe mode. i have not tested it with non-thread-safe and/or x64.
>
> to build the php_memcache.dll, i followed the instructions on https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild#building_pecl_extensions using:

```
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.0.2-src>buildconf
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.0.2-src>configure --disable-all 
  --enable-cli --enable-zlib --enable-hash --enable-session 
  --without-gd --with-bz2 --enable-memcache=shared
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.0.2-src>nmake
```