# windows 10 php 7.2 memcached

Tags: php, symfony, windows-10, memcached

When I am transferring project to Windows (framework symfony), issue appears when running the command Composer update. I realized that on the server module is missing php mencached version php 7.2. I cannot find anywhere the module, could any one suggest me where can I find it or how can I compile, and where can I get the sours code& how to compile it. 
Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952502/memcache-for-php7-on-windows
Using windows for php could lead you to lots of issues. Consider using vagrant or docker on windows.

Comment: How did you set up your Windows environment? Are you using something like XAMPP?

Comment: yes i using virtual server like xampp

Comment: Which kind of "issue" are you talking about? Is there any error message given?

Answer (score 2):

- check phpinfo() for found this information:

  Compiler: MSVC14

  Architecture: **x64**

  PHP Extension Build: API20160303,**NTS,VC14**
- Based on information in phpinfo(); choose right dll:

  Source: https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll
  Folder (based on example): **vc14 / x64 / nts**
- Copy to php_memcache.dll to \PHP\v7.1\ext
- Enable php_memcache in php.ini, add line:

  extension=php_memcache.dll
- Check if you see 'memcache' section in phpinfo();