# Install Memcached on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, memcached

While doing some web development, I needed to have Memcached (source code) installed on my local machine to closely simulate what was going on my server.

How to install Memcached on Windows?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Steps to install Memcached on Windows:

1. Download a stable version, in either [32-bit](https://static.runoob.com/download/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip) or [64-bit](https://static.runoob.com/download/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip) I have tested the 64-bit version.
2. Unzip it in some hard drive folder. For example `C:\memcached`
3. There will be `memcached.exe` file in the unzipped folder.
4. Open a command prompt (need to be opened as administrator).
5. Run `c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d install`

For start and stop run following command line

```
c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d start
c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d stop
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `cmd` as Administrator, otherwise service may fail to install.

Comment: https://memcached.org/downloads

Comment: use the complete URL,  copy and paste in browser for downloading memcached : for 64 bit : http://static.runoob.com/download/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip

Comment: Linking to binaries on some random Chinese website seems dodgy.

Comment: A [windows port](https://github.com/jefyt/memcached-windows) is now available on GitHub with binaries. It looks more trustworthy to me.

Comment: https://static.runoob.com/download/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip This is an official from memcached.org ? I can only download source code from official website. How I can install from source code?

Comment: Is this official?
Because, as I can read on the official repository, they do not provide official support for Windows. https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Install

Answer (score 1):

As told in some previous comments the v1.4.4 is sometimes coming from a trusted source, sometimes not and it becomes hard to find. But there is now a very stable Windows native port for both 32 bits and 64 bits versions.

https://github.com/jefyt/memcached-windows

It's running well on our two PHP servers (PHP7 and PHP8).
Hope this helps.

Another Cygwin version is also available here and runs well too
https://github.com/nono303/memcached

Comment: Hi b126, could you please help with how to configure it with PHP 8? What should we place in the extension directory of PHP, I didn't find the .dll file in the zip which I downloaded.

Comment: Do you already have a Memcached instance running? If so, then you can install the appropriate extensions for PHP that will use your Memcached instance. This describes how to do : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777857/how-to-install-and-use-memcached-in-windows-for-php

Comment: The PHP-MEMCACHED extension is available here: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached.

php_memcached.dll should go your \php\ext directory.
libmemcached.dll and libhashkit.dll should go to a path folder