# How do you configure memcached because i am new to the service

Tags: windows, memcached

How do you configure memcached to achieve better performance when gaming.

I stumbled upon memcached while trying to figure out more uses for a ramdisk and while searching for more uses for ramdisk I found that people have stopped using ramdisk and started using memcached.

And while searching for memcached I have found that memcached was usually designed for Linux but there is a version of memcached that was designed for windows. I have found the files of memcached for windows 32 and 64bit and I have used the following thread from the forum to install memcached for windows

[Install Memcached on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476616/install-memcached-on-windows/70606953#70606953)

But I'm curious on how memcached collects the data and how to take advantage of memcached in windows for gaming or to achieve better performance.

Comment: Windows already uses system memory to cache disk data. Installing a RAM disk will, at best, have no effect. Anyway, this question is off-topic (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: Thank you for your input but that's why my question is about memcached not ramdisk. I mentioned ramdisk because that's what brought me to the service memcached. I also brought up that I am new to the memcached service and I noticed a lot of people talking about memcached but each one I have read hasn't answered my question.  Which is why I asked me question above.