# Session variables destroyed when hosting with Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

After hosting my website with Heroku, my PHP session variables are getting destroyed. Any idea why? My code has a simple $_SESSION['course'] variable. I had no problems with localhost using MAMP, but after hosting with Herkou the variable doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing with Herkou?

Comment: See this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-sessions

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks. How do I install Memcached on Windows? The guides I see on the internet are vague

Comment: This thread looks useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777857/how-to-install-and-use-memcached-in-windows-for-php