# yaml xampp warning: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll'

Tags: php, windows, xampp, yaml, warnings

I installed the recent versions of xampp for windows and yaml on my PC with windows 8.1 64bit.

The versions were

- xampp-win32-7.0.9-1-VC14-installer.exe
- php_yaml-2.0.0rc8-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip

I put the line of `extension=php_yaml.dll` to the end of `php.ini` file.
I copied `php_yaml.dll` to `C:/xampp/php/ext` folder.
I copied `yaml.dll` to `C:/xampp/apache/bin` folder.

`phpinfo();` command displayed that yaml was enabled.

But bad warning still appeared on command prompt when typing `php` command:

> $ php
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll' - The spec
>   ified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll' - The specified
>    module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

See it on screenshots:

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Hi mate, I'm getting the same issue. Can you please suggest what solution did work ?

Comment: Add `;C:\xampp\apache\bin` to PATH Windows environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `;C:\xampp\apache\bin` to `PATH` Windows environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by downloading the correct version of yaml. The yaml Version has to match the installed PHP version. Make sure that you match the thread-safe and non-thread-safe option with your PHP aswell.

[How to check if your PHP is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799843/find-if-the-installed-php-is-threadsafe-or-nonthreadsafe#:%7E:text=Open%20a%20phpinfo()%20and,%2Di%7Cfindstr%20%22Thread%22)