# Strange characters in php log

Tags: php, encoding, phalcon

I'm tring to install phalcon framework on my server, which is supposed to be quite easy:

1. Add php_phalcon.dll in extensions dir
2. Add `extension = php_phalcon.dll 'to php.ini
3. Restart the server

But for some reason the extension can not be loaded. And I can not get the reason because warning messages in the log file appear like this:

`[03-Dec-2017 17:12:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_phalcon.dll' - �� ������ �������� �����.
 in Unknown on line 0`

How can I make log messages become readable?

Additional information might be useful:

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)
- IIS 7
- PHP: I tried two versions: 5.6 (x86) and 7.1 (x64)

Comment: Is it that library that was removed in php7 http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php ?

Comment: But it logs the same about php_pahlcon.dll. I edited the question to not confuse.

Comment: As you're putting this in your `v7.1` directory, Make sure you're grabbing the right file from the following four: phalcon_x64_vc14_php7.1.0_3.2.4.zip, phalcon_x64_vc14_php7.1.0_3.2.4_nts.zip, phalcon_x86_vc14_php7.1.0_3.2.4.zip, phalcon_x86_vc14_php7.1.0_3.2.4_nts.zip
Do a phpinfo() to find this information for the architecture PHP was built in (not your computer's architecture per se) , and whether it was built in thread-safe mode or not.  Find the "PHP Extension Build" section. if it says NTS on the end, then grab the NTS version.

Comment: Just a guess, not sure if this may be the cause, but: Did you download the correct dll from the point of view of the thread safetiness? (TS vs NTS)? How to check whether your PHP is TS or NTS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5799843/3219919

Comment: Also make sure you have the PDO extension enabled, and it's loaded before Phalcon.

Comment: Thank you Ultimater and  ZoliSzabó! Using NTS version solved the problem with the phalcon extension. But does it explain strange symbols in log file? Doesn't it suppesed to be some readable message like 'The specified module could not be found.'?