# Which php binary should I use?

Tags: php, windows

http://windows.php.net/download/ - There is a VC9 x86 thread safe/non-thread safe versions of the PHP executable. What should I use and what is its significance from a dev perspective?

Comment: There is a reasonable explanation about that [here](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/my_word/difference_between_php_thread_safe_and_non_thread_safe_binaries)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only time you want the non thread safe version is if you are going to be using PHP as a CGI interface with IIS.