# How to install Zend OPcache Extension + PHP >= 5.4 on Windows

Tags: php, windows, opcache

Is it possible to install Zend OPcache module for PHP 5.4.29 in Windows Environment? I have downloaded OPCache that was meant to be compatible with PHP 5.4 but

```
php -v
```

does not show anything new loaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zend OPcache extension is compatible with 5.3.* 5.4.* and PHP 5.5.*

You should download the [source-code](https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus) of the extension and compile yourself or try to download [pre-compiled windows version here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/opcache/) and call the extension in your php.ini like this:

```
zend_extension=/path/to/opcache.dll
```

**Notice** :

1. There are multiple versions exists for windows binaries: Thread Safe and Non-Thread Safe. You should pick the correct one according your needs. Learn more about TS and NTS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204758/php-thread-safe-and-non-thread-safe-for-windows).
2. Each build has a php version in filename. In your case, you should use `php_opcache-7.X.X-5.4-XX-XX-XXX.zip`.

**Update**
Since opcache is a part of php core for a long time and this question is highly visible on search engines, I wanted to update my answer.

According to documentation, enabling opcache using following lines in php.ini:

```
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
opcache.enable=On
opcache.enable_cli=On
```

then restarting the web server (IIS I guess) should be enough.

Comment: According to [PECL documentation](http://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache), PHP 5.2.* is also supported.

Comment: I have installed `Drupal` on `PHP 7.3.1` environment, and it did ask for `opcache` extension to be installed, but there seems to be NOT any new version of `opcache` out there, nothing for `PHP 7.3.1`, so, am I mistaken, or is `Drupal` asking for the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @edigu's answer, here are some additional considerations for Windows Server 2012R2/IIS 8+ users. PHP version is 7.2. I'm using the old Codeplex version of PHP Manager, so perhaps these steps don't apply if you're using the [recently revamped version](https://www.phpmanager.xyz/).

- Enabling `php_opcache.dll` in the extensions GUI doesn't work. In php.ini, find the line that says `extension=php_opcache.dll` rename it to `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll`.
- Find every line that begins with `opcache.` and make sure it isn't commented out.
- In addition to the `On` and `Off` values for toggling properties, such as in `opcache.enable=On`, you can also use `1` and `0` respectively.

Restart the site in IIS, then the Zend OPcache section on the phpinfo() screen should report everything up and running.