# Is dual PHP install possible

Tags: php, apache, iis-7

I have the thread safe version of PHP setup on my machine as I previously had to work with PHP with Apache but now I have to use PHP with IIS to integrate with a SQL Server database and so I believe I need the Non Thread Safe PHP installation.  Is it possible for me to have both installed and use seperate locations, i.e. C:\PHP for the Apache thread safe and C:\PHP_NTS for the IIS non thread safe without them conflicting?  Unless of course I just use the Apache install for connecting to SQL Server but I think this would be troublesome.  My operating system is Windows 7

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204758/php-thread-safe-and-non-thread-safe-for-windows? If you don't use fast cgi you can use thread-safe php with iis