# What does thread safe mean in a PHP context?

Tags: php, thread-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [What is thread safe or non thread safe in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914)

What does it mean when something is or is not thread safe?

For example, setlocale() in PHP is not thread safe:

> The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If
>   you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS or Apache
>   on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while
>   a script is running, though the script itself never called
>   setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different
>   threads of the same process at the same time, changing the
>   process-wide locale using setlocale().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

What does this practically mean? Is it a good thing that something is thread safe or not?

Under what conditions do you need a thread-safe or non-thread-safe solution to your problems?

Comment: Did you read that part where it explains that it pertains to certain webserver setups only? It's not something you can choose or use. And `setlocale` is a good example of potential side-effects. (Except that it actually works per-thread on recent Windows versions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread safe is a good thing, it means whilst there may be multiple concurrent threads, they are talking to each other in a safe way that won't have race conditions, concurrency issues, etc.

> Thread safety is a computer programming concept applicable in the
>   context of multi-threaded programs. A piece of code is thread-safe if
>   it only manipulates shared data structures in a thread-safe manner,
>   which enables safe execution by multiple threads at the same time.
>   There are various strategies for making thread-safe data structures.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).