# At some times, server can not change locale

Tags: php, apache, locale

I have a problem with a PHP script sometimes triggering weird warnings in the Apache error log :

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.utf8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.utf8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.utf8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.utf8)
```

Below is the code generating this warning. (it is used to configure gettext).

```
    $lang='fr_FR.utf8';
    $filename = 'default';
    putenv("LC_ALL=$lang");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
    bindtextdomain($filename, './config/locale');
    bind_textdomain_codeset($filename, "UTF-8");
    textdomain($filename);
```

The weird thing is that the warning does not systematically appear. 
If I restart Apache, it will not appear for some minutes (i.e. serving hundreds of requests without any warning) and then it will progressively start appearing.

Thank you

Comment: Did you read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes)?

Comment: yes. I thought though that this was not relevant to me since Apache on my server is running in prefork mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setlocale` is not thread safe (See [What does thread safe mean in a PHP context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334123/what-does-thread-safe-mean-in-php-context). That's why the Zend Framework implements their own Locale system.

Comment: thought this wouldn't be a problem as my Apache is running in prefork mode?