# High CPU load but low CPU usage and RAM usage

Tags: performance, nginx, webserver, php

I am running a mobile website to get the live running status of any train in India. It is http://www.spoturtrain.com . The full code is written in PHP and Nginx is used as the webserver, php-fpm is used as the application server. All php requests are proxied to the app server. During peak traffic hours in the morning, the system load shoots up to 4 but the CPU% and the memory usage is low. Please take a look at the snapshot of the top command of the server.

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Are you having some kind of problem?

Comment: How many processors / cores are available?  The rule of thumb for maximum load is that a load of *greater* than the number of procs means it's overloaded.  So if you have 4 cores and the load hovers from 3-4, nothing is horribly wrong, even if it might not be what you want it to be.  Also watch iowait.

Comment: @Charles The cpu in my case has only one core.

Answer (score 2):

Th %CPU displayed in the bottom section is per-thread, which means the percentage of one CPU core used by the indicated thread.  The CPU(s) section indicates the total amount of available CPU that is being utilized, so it is possible to have one thread reporting that it is using 100% CPU, while only 25% (4 core) or 12.5% (8 core) of the overall CPU cycles are being consumed.

[Analyzing thread CPU usage on Linux](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg0001475cb4a-1190e2e0f74-8000_1007.html)

You don't really ask a question, so it's hard to tell if you are wanting some advice or just asking to have the numbers explained. As @Charles states, a typical "acceptable" load is 1 per CPU core before noticeable performance degradation occurs, but in the case of PHP running on most web servers, you may (but probably won't in most cases) start noticing problems at anything above 1.  Whether or not you do will largely depend on your disk and network I/O.

Whether or not the performance is acceptable for your application isn't something I can answer, but you can take a look at this thread for more places to jump into the options for getting your web server to thread requests.

[What is thread safe or non thread safe in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php)

Whether or not you can do anything about it depends on your hosting situation.

Comment: My question is why my system load is greater during peak hours. My application is not CPU intensive. It does a netwrok I/O (API) call to get data. That's all.

Comment: Your system load is higher because the system is doing more work. That's what load measures, more or less.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know that my system is doing more work. My question is why ?

Comment: There's a reason that this thread died: It is baffling that you state, "During peak traffic hours" followed by, "I know that my system is doing more work. My question is why ?" It's doing more work because it is answering more requests. Are you expecting for it to do the same amount of work when the number of requests increases? The reason it is doing more work is very, very obvious - It is answering more requests.

Comment: @ChrisOstmo Thanks for your reply. I get it. I have been so dumb to ask this. Sorry for having wasted your time.