# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Threaded' not found in /var/www/ ... .php on line nn

Tags: php, multithreading, centos, yum

I've installed php70 using the Remi repository on Centos 7 and need to get thread safety enabled as I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

running:

```
php70 -i|grep -i thread
```

I get:

```
Thread Safety => disabled
```

I have tried installing the *php-pecl-pthreads* package via yum but the error persists.

Investigating further (as per this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347168/thread-safety-enabled-server-php)), it would appear that thread safety is how the version of php is compiled and not just a php extension.

Should I be using a different repo to have php 7.0 with thread safety? If so, which repo is best? Does it even exist yet in a repo or should I be compiling php 70 with thread safety from source?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command line, you need to use the **zts-php** command.

```
# zts-php -i|grep -i thread
Thread Safety => enabled
```

Notices:

- the **zts-php** command is only available in **php-cli** package from remi-php70 repository (not in the php70-php-cli SCL package)
- the **Threaded** class command is provided by the pthreads extension (which requires a ZTS build) and is only available for CLI.

Comment: Hi Remi, 

I'm unable to execute that command, and doing 'yum search zts' only returns the php-pecl-pthreads package. The repo I'm using is http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm Cheers.

Comment: How have you installed PHP 7 ?   "php-cli" package from "remi-php70" repository provides this command (php70-php-cli, doesn't), see the Wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Awesome, thanks Remi! The wizard made it a heap easier. Merci!