# How to resolve dll load error

Tags: php, php-5.4

This is the error that is noted in the error log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.4\ext\php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

This is the ini file:

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.4\ext\"
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

The file exits in the directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.4\ext\php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

phpinfo.php does not show a MSSQL Server section.

So for some reason, the dll is not getting loaded. I have tried both the thread-safe and non-thread-safe.  The non-thread-safe does not show the load error, but it still doesn't load (doesn't show in PHP Info, nor lets the code run with the ms_sql functions.

Comment: did you check if that path is legit? "could not be found" is pretty explicit...

Comment: Yes the path is legit, I just added it to the above.

Comment: "php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll" is compiled on 64bit or x86? Note "_ts" means "Thread Safe" read about in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php

Comment: I am actually not sure if they are 64 or x86, will check on that.

Comment: PHP 5.4 is 32 bit, and the php_sql_srv_54_ts.dll is also a 32 bit version. I tried the unofficial 64 bit version of the driver and got a `- %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` error.

Comment: @GregGum Use `@username`, for the reason that if you do not use your comment will ever get in my "inbox" and for this reason it took me to know that you had answered me.

Comment: You using "Thread Safe"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, thanks for the comments.  This is no longer an issue that needs resolving.

Comment: @GregGum You got the solution, if so post an answer to his own question, could help other users.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, unfortunately, I was unable to find a solution. I finally gave up on it.

Comment: @GregGum Have you given up? If you enter the version that your PHP is thread-safe or not, someone probably would have succeeded in formulating an answer.
I was waiting since 2. I do not understand why you gave up :)