# Installing php_phalcon.dll on wamp server 2.5 x64

Tags: wamp, wampserver, phalcon

Well this is my first time on phalcon, I want to try it out, but I can't activate the extension. I am using WampServer 2.5 x64.

Here's my php version:

[image: phpinfo()]

According to this, I tried 2 versions from their download page:

[image: phalcon download page]

Restarted wamp several times, but I still get a warning sign on the extension:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing 'NTS' means 'Not Thread Safe', you need to look at your PHP installation to see if your PHP installation is Thread-Safe (TS), and then use the right DLL.

Comment: Yay, after I added the `extension=php_phalcon.dll` line and changed the .dll file to thread safe, it activated. Thanks!

Comment: I've provided the answer as an answer below, I'd be grateful if you could accept + upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NTS` means Not-Thread-Safe, information on PHP's Thread Safety feature [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php).

From the question I linked:

> A Thread Safe version should be used if you install PHP as an Apache
>   module, as a Worker MPM (multi-processing model).
>
> The Non Thread Safe version should be used if you install PHP as a CGI
>   binary.

You need to find out whether your PHP installation is thread-safe, to do so:

1. Navigate to your PHP Info page (if you do not have one, create a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.
2. Load the page, and look for the **Thread Safety** line; if enabled it will say `Enabled` (or `True` on some installations).

If Thread Safety is enabled, you must use the **thread safe** version of the extension, which in your case is `Phalcon 1.3.4 - Windows x64 for PHP 5.5.0 (VC11)`.

Comment: Did you get the last line wrong? Cause Thread safety is enabled and it worked with `Phalcon 1.3.4 - Windows x64 for PHP 5.5.0 (VC11)`. :)

Comment: @ДејанИгњатов I did, d'oh! Thanks for pointing that out, now corrected.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Just for future reference. WAMPServer always required thread safe modules as PHP is configured to run as an Apache module and it is run on windows, therefore it is a threaded model and not a forked model.