# httpd: how can I understand where the error in httpd.conf is

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to install PHP on Apache httpd server 2.4 on Windows. Yes, I know that that is extremely simple. But after adding the following three lines httpd start operation fails.

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
```

I'm not trying to asc what is done wrong after giving you three lines, I want to know can I somehow understand where the problem is (in error.log I do not have any message about errors while start).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load php dll file using `LoadFile` directive:

```
LoadFile "c:/server/php/php5ts.dll"
```

in this case, `php5ts.dll` is name of the dll file, but you may need to change it to `php5nts.dll`  based on whether you use [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1623914/440546).