# Is PHP-FPM thread safe

Tags: php, thread-safety

I have a custom PHP module that depends on an external library that is not thread safe. Does FPM use threads or processes to handle requests? Is it safe to use a non-threadsafe php module with PHP-FPM?

Comment: Maybe this will help you with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php?lq=1

Comment: Thank you @C0dekid.php. The answers in the linked question are about php-fcgi and mod_php. I am interested in PHP-FPM. I want to know if the process pool in FPM uses threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question in a PHP IRC channel and was told that PHP-FPM is always non-threaded, as it makes no sense to build it as thread safe. Since each request is handled by a separate process (which is re-used) in PHP-FPM, it should be safe to use the module with PHP-FPM.