# PHP OCI8 extensions not working with PHP 7 64 bit

Tags: php, windows, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have installed APACHE 2.4 x64 and PHP7 x64 and download PHP OCI 64bit libraries but the problem is that whenever I run PHP script from cli it says

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'E:\software\server\php-7.0.11-Win32-VC14-x64\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' -
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Also when I invoke the webapplication from URL it says

> Call to undefined function oci_pconnect()

The OCI extension I downloaded are also 64bit. Here is the link:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.2/php_oci8-2.1.2-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip

Can someone guide on this problem.

Comment: I don't use Oracle but I run the same WAMP version so I tested v2.1.2 like you and v2.1.1 and both won't load. Seems like the DLLs are bad.

Comment: php5 and php7 are incompatible, so make sure your php_oci.dll is made for php7. Note: you could start testing with standalone PHP (PHP.EXE) first, without Apache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably mixed TS (thread safe) and NTS (non-thread safe) versions. These will not work together. Find out more about PHP thread safety [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1623914/3775731).

PHP [7.0.11 NTS x64](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.0.11-nts-Win32-VC14-x64.zip), OCI8 [2.1.2 NTS x64](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.2/php_oci8-2.1.2-7.0-nts-vc14-x64.zip), and InstantClient [11.2.0.4.0 x64](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/instantclient/11204/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip) work perfectly well together (I've just downloaded these three files and tested them in a fresh Win2K8 environment).

Remember to install the latest VC14 runtime (Visual Studio 2015) and to modify your `PATH` system environment variable to include the directories of PHP and the InstantClient, e.g. `C:\php;C:\instantclient_11_2`.

Comment: I used Thread Safe packages. The problem was found to be with Instant client files.. it was resolved by copying all the files of instantclient in c:\windows and c:\windows\system32 directories. Your comment of specifying its path in Environment variable makes more sense.. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: i have same issue but my issue is not resolving by just copying files in  c:\windows and c:\windows\system32 directories. please check my question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640455/php-oci8-ext-not-loading-unable-to-load-dynamic-library?noredirect=1#comment80230275_46640455