# php oci8 ext not loading Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to connect my PHP 7.0 with Oracle database(11g release 2) for that I download dll files of oci8 extension from https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.1.7/windows and copy php_oci8.dll and `php_oci8_11g.dll in my xampp/php/ext` after that I restart my xampp server.

```
My System type is: 64bit operating system x64 based processor
```

when using 7.0 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64 extension getting this error on cmd

[image]

when using 7.0 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x84 extension getting this error on cmd

[image]

why these dynamic libraries are not loading what I need to do to connect php 7 with Oracle 11g release 2 in 64-bit windows 10 operating system please help me about this

Comment: May be this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664801/php-oci8-extensions-not-working-with-php-7-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Please check phpinfo to see if thread safety is enabled on your XAMPP server. (It  seem to be enabled by default on xampp.) Also, check if your XAMPP is 32-bit or 64-bit. (There seems to be only 32-bit version available on Windows?) Then download OCI8 pecl package accordingly.

Here is what I got:

[PHPInfo on my Windows Xampp server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyJgi.jpg)

Hence, I downloaded "7.1 Thread Safe (TS) x86".

FYI, oci8_2.1.8 is released this week. It fixes a critical reference count issue.

Comment: i resolve this issue by download 7.1 Thread Safe (TS).i was facing this issue because i was using nts .zip  files now my oci8 extension is working fine in my 64bit windows thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed Did you get  "7.1 Thread Safe (TS) x86" or  "7.1 Thread Safe (TS) x64"?

Comment: it x86 because php is 32bit